# How can I get Skype to run on a MD700 tablet?

Tags: adb, tablet, skype, microphone

My uncle bought a cheap MD700 tablet (running Android 4.1.2) and strongly desired to use Skype on it, but for some reason the application didn't recognize microphone input. All it could be heard on the other end was a constant, static buzz.

I started trying older app versions until I found one that worked, and he stuck with that one until it was finally phased out, months later. Now, all accepted versions exhibit the same buggy behaviour.

The integrated microphone and the microphone jack were ruled out as culprits through testing. Other apps record audio flawlessly, and the issue persists even when using headphones. I believe the evidence points to a Skype bug or compatibility problem. A restart to factory settings didn't help. There are no ROMs available for this tablet, so updating Android itself is a no-go.

Running out of options, I connected the device to a Linux station and ran a logcat command during a test call. I considered some dalvikvm, nativecrypto and networkstats entries to contain no diagnostic value, so I filtered them out.

The result can be found [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=41770599686150949846).

While applying some amateurish debugging skills, the following entries catched my eye:

- W/AudioStreamInHandler( 4436): read but no streamin
- D/AudioYusuHardware( 4436): Audio_Match_Force_device Force_config=0x1
- D/AudioSPELayer( 4436): 0

Alas, they do not give that much of a hint for the non-Android developer.

Any ideas on how to proceed or what to test for?

Thank you all in advance.